# "conditions under which" or "conditions in which"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is (more) correct?

> conditions under which

or

> conditions in which

Example:

> We should consider the conditions in/under which such behavior is performed.

Comment: They're both correct. Why do you think one should be 'more correct' than the other?

Comment: @TusharRaj I don't know. Scrupulosity?

Comment: Perhaps an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+these+conditions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunder%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUnder%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthat%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20these%20conditions%3B%2Cc0) can be of help?

Comment: A sentence with a combined usage of both `in` and `under` might help: _The interesting thing about the Regan experiment, however, is that the relationship between liking and compliance was completely wiped out `in the condition under which` subjects had been given a Coke by Joe._ --Influence The Psychology of Persuasion by Robert B. Cialdini

Answer (score 4):

There is a subtle difference in meaning between the two forms.  The phrase 'the conditions in which' implies a given ("environmental") context over which one may not have control.  'The conditions under which' implies that there are provisos or rules in force that will have direct bearing on behaviour.  Both phrases are grammatically correct.

Comment: Hello Vanessa. Welcome to ELU. I'm upvoting your answer as it's helpful. However, please know that most good answers here include some form of  citation, for instance, a link to a reliable online resource that corroborates what they're saying.